# Summing Values Linked by a Foreign Key In Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

i'm struggling with creating a query or some other alternate method that works out a balance from the sum of a table where the foreign key is equal.

Here are the two table structures:

ProductLines

```
ProductLineID      | AutoNumber
CompanyName        | Short Text
OrderID            | Number
ReferenceNumber    | Short Text
ProductDescription | Short Text
Quantity           | Number
PricePerUnit       | Currency
LineTotal          | Calculated
DueDate            | Date/Time
```

DeliveryLines

```
DeliveryLineID   | AutoNumber
DeliveryID       | Number
ProductLineID    | Number
DeliveryQuantity | Number
```

A Product Line can have many Delivery Lines, hence the foreign key in Delivery Lines

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT [DeliveryLines].[ProductLineID], 
Sum([DeliveryLines]![DeliveryQuantity]) AS QuantityDelivered
FROM [DeliveryLines] GROUP BY [DeliveryLines].[ProductLineID];
```

This correctly works out the sums of each product line. The problem is that I need to be able to have it linked to the [Product Lines].[ProductLineID] instead so that a user can retrieve all product line information and have it retrieve the balance (along with all the other columns) for each one. I also need it to have an exception for when a product line DOES NOT have any delivery lines, and preferably shows the [ProductLines].[Quantity] instead.

Any help would be much appreciated,

Andy

Comment: Just `Left Join` Productline with your query on LineID and replace the Null values (no DeliveryLanes) with `[ProductLines].[Quantity]`  (e.g. `Nz(QuantityDelivered,[ProductLines].[Quantity])`).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a simple `JOIN`

```
SELECT ProductLines.ProductLineID, CompanyName, OrderID, [any other fields],
  SUM(Nz(DeliveryQuantity,0)) AS QuantityDelivered
FROM ProductLines
  LEFT JOIN DeliveryLines ON ProductLines.ProductLineID=DeliveryLines.ProductLineID
GROUP BY ProductLines.ProductLineID, CompanyName, OrderID, [any other fields]
```

You only need brackets if a name has spaces or special characters and you only need table names for fields when more than one table in the query has a field with the same name.

You can avoid `GROUP BY` every single field from `ProductLines` by using `FIRST` like this:

```
SELECT ProductLines.ProductLineID, FIRST(CompanyName) AS FirstCompanyName
…
GROUP BY ProductLines.ProductLineID
```

Comment: As OP wants all  `ProductLines` (those without `DeliveryLines` too) a `Left Join` is needed.  Any benefit not using his query as subselect?

Comment: I generally prefer to not use subqueries unless the problem is too complex for JOINs or a subquery will be used multiple times. Just a matter of taste.

Comment: I would have joined on his query instead of `DeliveryLines` as it seems better readable to me. In addition OP would have used his preliminary work and substituting the missing `QuantityDelivered` would be easier. Your answer is still missing this part ;)

Comment: OK, thanks for the help so far, but still having an issue. Whenever I include a `JOIN` and the `SUM` or `GROUP BY` I get the Error: `Your query does not include the specified expression 'ProductLineID' as part of an aggregate function.

Comment: What I have so far:

`SELECT [ProductLines].[ProductLineID], [ProductLines].[CompanyName], [ProductLines].[OrderID], [ProductLines].[ReferenceNumber], [ProductLines].[ProductDescription], [ProductLines].[Quantity], [ProductLines].[PricePerUnit],  [ProductLines].[LineTotal], [ProductLines].[DueDate], SUM(Nz([DeliveryQuantity],[ProductLines].[Quantity])) AS QuantityDelivered
FROM [ProductLines] LEFT JOIN [DeliveryLines] ON [ProductLines].[ProductLineID] = [DeliveryLines].[ProductLineID] GROUP BY [DeliveryLines].[ProductLineID];`

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` statement has to include everything in your `SELECT` statement that is not aggregated (so in your case everything but the SUMed field).

Comment: @AndyP1963 But if you group on all your sum gets wrong results. Thats why SunKnight0 has suggested using `First?  on all cols of `ProductLines` except `ProductlineID`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```sql
SELECT
    [Product Lines].[Product Line ID]
  , [Product Lines].[Company Name]
  , [Product Lines].[Order ID]
  , [Product Lines].[Reference Number]
  , [Product Lines].[Product Description]
  , [Product Lines].[Quantity]
  , [Product Lines].[Price Per Unit]
  , [Product Lines].[Line Total]
  , [Product Lines].[Due Date]
  , SUM(Nz([Delivery Quantity],0)) AS QuantityDelivered
FROM
    [Product Lines]
    LEFT JOIN
        [Delivery Lines]
    ON
        [Product Lines].[Product Line ID] = [Delivery Lines].[Product Line ID]
GROUP BY
    [Product Lines].[Product Line ID]
  , [Product Lines].[Company Name]
  , [Product Lines].[Order ID]
  , [Product Lines].[Reference Number]
  , [Product Lines].[Product Description]
  , [Product Lines].[Quantity]
  , [Product Lines].[Price Per Unit]
  , [Product Lines].[Line Total]
  , [Product Lines].[Due Date]
;
```

It's messy and long winded but it works.

Comment: [How to format SQL Code](https://www.sqlinform.com/online-sql-formatter/)

Answer (score 0):

My solution with your starting query as subquery and the `QuantityDelivered` replaced if Null.

```sql
SELECT
    [ProductLines].[ProductLineID]
  , [ProductLines].[CompanyName]
  , [ProductLines].[OrderID]
  , [ProductLines].[ReferenceNumber]
  , [ProductLines].[ProductDescription]
  , [ProductLines].[PricePerUnit]
  , [ProductLines].[LineTotal]
  , [ProductLines].[DueDate]
  , Nz(t.QuantityDelivered,ProductLines.Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM
    ProductLines
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                [DeliveryLines].[ProductLineID]
              , SUM([DeliveryLines].[DeliveryQuantity]) AS QuantityDelivered
            FROM
                [DeliveryLines]
            GROUP BY
                [DeliveryLines].[ProductLineID]
        )
        AS t
    ON
        ProductLines.ProductLineID=t.ProductLineID
```